# make: *** [/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libc++.so] Error 1 when building Cyanogenmod

Tags: android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to build Cyanogenmod 12.1 for a device for which there already exist nightlies (hlte - Samsung Galaxy Note 3), but am encountering some problems building.

I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04-based Docker container (Dockerfile at https://github.com/jameshiew/docker-aosp-builder/blob/a3fef049e9963db42a9168207d590a82638181b7/Dockerfile) - I've tried to match the environment as described at https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html as closely as possible.

The first thing I did was do `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.1` in a blank directory then `repo sync` which all checked out fine.

Then I did `breakfast cm_hlte-userdebug` (to check out repos relevant to my device) then added `<project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_samsung" path="vendor/samsung" remote="github" />` to a local manifest and `repo sync`ed again to get propietary blobs for my device.

I then did `lunch cm_hlte-userdebug && mka` but kept getting odd errors of the sort `libnativehelper/JniInvocation.cpp:165: error: unsupported reloc 43` thrown about.

After looking at this discussion on Cyanogenmod's gerrit by people having the same problem - http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/120824/ - and another discussion on Debian's bug tracker - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808206), I did `make clean`, cleared the ccache and tried `WITHOUT_HOST_CLANG=true mka`. The build progressed further (no more `unsupported reloc` errors) but now (in separate two runs) it is stopping at the same point (error output below).

The main error is:

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libc++.so] Error 1
```

Fuller output:

```
Install: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/lib/libc++.so
...
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_handlers.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(exception.o): multiple definition of 'std::unexpected()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_handlers.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::~bad_array_new_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::~bad_array_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::~bad_array_new_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::~bad_array_new_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::set_new_handler(void (*)())'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_handlers.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::get_new_handler()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_handlers.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::bad_array_new_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::bad_array_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_new_length::bad_array_new_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(new.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_array_length::bad_array_length()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(cxa_new_delete.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::logic_error::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::runtime_error::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::underflow_error::~underflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::underflow_error::~underflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::underflow_error::~underflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::range_error::~range_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::range_error::~range_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::range_error::~range_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::logic_error::~logic_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::domain_error::~domain_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::domain_error::~domain_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::domain_error::~domain_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::logic_error::~logic_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): multiple definition of 'std::logic_error::~logic_error()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(stdexcept.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::what() const'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::bad_typeid()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): multiple definition of 'std::bad_typeid::bad_typeid()'
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_intermediates/libc++.a(typeinfo.o): previous definition here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libc++.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
make: Leaving directory `/aosp'
```

I have looked around quite a bit but am not sure what the problem might be at this point; whether it's related to the compiler, the checked out code (or lack of), the environment, or something else. Would anyone have some hint at a glance of what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your android root path:

`cp /usr/bin/ld.gold prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6/x86_64-linux/bin/ld`